# Swift: fixed searchBar into tableView header

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a `tableView` with a `searchBar` inside the table header.

Everything is working well except when I scroll down the rows, the search bar disappear.

How can I make it fixed?

Comment: Is your search bar in tableview section header. If yes then how many sections do you have in tableview. IF 1 then set the style of your tableview to UITableViewStylePlain and it should stay fixed.

Comment: yes, and yes, and is already plain

Comment: Use delegate method viewForHeaderInSection. Create your custom view add things in this view then return this view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no a way to maintain the header of a tableView fixed, but an useful approach when you need a unique header, could be to use UIViewController instead of UITableViewController, and set the header (UIView that contains searchBar) above the tableView.

Comment: thank you, but with this approach I should reorganize everything. I prefer to avoid it. :P

Comment: tableView:ViewForHeaderInSection: is also an option to achieve your task. In this case table view style needs to be plain.